# After running successfully BackgroundWorker() the rest of the program is not executed

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I am using a BackgroundWorker() to execute a long running query in the background while I am presenting a pop up window that my execution is running.

Here is how I call the bg_worker()

```cs
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace TestEnvironment
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>

    public partial class ProgressBarTemplate : Window
    {
        private CreateProjectScreen _CreateProjectScreen;
        private LoginScreen _LoginScreen;

        public ProgressBarTemplate()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static int RunCalculationsMethod(string connectionstring, string foldername)
        {
            bool exists = Directory.Exists(foldername);

            if (!exists)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(foldername);
            }

            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
                {
                    var calculations_query = "SELECT * FROM table1");

                    using SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(calculations_query, sqlConnection);

                    sqlConnection.Open();

                    sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 60 * 10;

                    int NumbderOfRecords = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    return NumbderOfRecords;
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                return -100;
            }
        }

        private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            
            worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();           
        }

        void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            int IsSuccessful = RunCalculationsMethod("Server=localhost;Database=DB_Name;Integrated Security=SSPI", String.Format("C:\\folder_path\\"));
        }

        void BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // This is called on the UI thread when the DoWork method completes
            // so it's a good place to hide busy indicators, or put clean up code

            try
            {
                this.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("DQ Calculations completed successfully", "Information", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code above is placed in a window called ProgressBarTemplate()

And what I want is to call the background_worker on button click, of a button placed in my MainWindow

So my MainWindow has the following button click

```cs
private void RunCalculationsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //RunCalculationsMethod(SQLServerConnectionDetails(), String.Format("C:\\DQ_Findings_{0}", HomePageTab.Header.ToString().Split(" - ")[1]));
            try
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
                {
                    ProgressBarTemplate win_progressbar = new ProgressBarTemplate();
                    win_progressbar.Show();
                    //RunCalculationsMethod(SQLServerConnectionDetails(), String.Format("C:\\DQ_folder_test\\Findings\\"));
                }); // The code runs up to this point.
                
                //The code below is not executed for a reason, which I am trying to solve with this question
                List<SucessfulCompletion> reportsucessfulcompletion = new List<SucessfulCompletion>();
                reportsucessfulcompletion = SuccessfulCalculationsTimestamp(SQLServerConnectionDetails());

                if (reportsucessfulcompletion[0].Result==1)
                {
                    //Enable is only if successfull
                    PreviewCalculationsButton.IsEnabled = true;
                    PreviewReportButton.IsEnabled = true;

                    //add textbox of sucess
                    TickButtonSymbolCalculations.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    SQLSuccessfulTextCalculations.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    XerrorSymbolCalculations.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                    SQLFailedTextCalculations.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                    SQLSuccessfulTextCalculations.Text = String.Format("Completed On: {0}", reportsucessfulcompletion[0].Timestampvalue);
                }
                else
                {
                    //add textbox of fail
                    TickButtonSymbolCalculations.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                    SQLSuccessfulTextCalculations.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                    XerrorSymbolCalculations.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    SQLFailedTextCalculations.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    SQLFailedTextCalculations.Text = String.Format("Failed On: {0}", reportsucessfulcompletion[0].Timestampvalue);
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                return;
            }
        }
```

On button click I start the bg_worder by calling the window ProgressBarTemplate(). Although after completing the task the code to generate some text and enable the visibility of some buttons they it is not executed. Why is this happening? Am I missing something?

Comment: This is horrible code. I can't tell when UI ends and threaded logic begins. your code probably does everything in the invoke method i.e. UI thread.

Comment: @Bizhan The problem is on my first code snippet (aka BG Worker) or about the MainWindow (the second code snippet)? :)

Comment: I don't think you should be creating the progress bar via the dispatcher. You are already in the UI thread in the button click event handler, so you should be able to just create it directly.

Comment: @allan if you refer to the ```Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate { ...});``` I did this because C# was giving me an error about the STA thread error

Comment: @NikSp forget about BGW. That's an obsolete class fully replaced by `Task.Run` since 2012. Instead of putting the calculations in the progress window, a simple `var results=await Task.Run(()=>SomeHeavyComputing());` in your `click` or `rendered` handler would be enough, allowing you to update the UI before and after the async operation without `Invoke`

Comment: @NikSp to update the progress window, use the `IProgress<T>` interface and the `Progress<T>` class, to publish notifications from inside `SomeHeavyComputing` and have the update run on the UI thread itself

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos is it convenient to post an answer with your suggestions. Because clearly I am out-of-date in the code I have written. The threads I am searching in SO are at least 5 years old.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if you may you can also join here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222516/background-worker

Comment: So that suggests a threading issue. Have you tried including  Dispatcher.Run()  after showing the new window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is a bit unclear, so I'll just post how it should be done.

BGW is an obsolete class fully replaced by `Task.Run` and [Progress< T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1?view=netcore-3.1) since 2012. There's no need to use either BGW or `Invoke` when `async/await` are available.

Instead of putting the calculations in the progress window, you can use an asynchronous event handler, perform any calculations in the background and update the UI once the background operation completes. The progress form doesn't seem to report any progress, so all that's needed is to display and hide it. The code could be as simple as  :

```
private async void RunCalculationsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var win_progressbar = new ProgressBarTemplate();
    win_progressbar.Show();
    try
    {
        //Update the UI
        var results=await Task.Run(()=> RunCalculationsMethod(...));
        //Update the UI
    }
    finally
    {
        win_progressbar.Close();
    }
}
```

The `try/finally` is used to ensure the form is closed even if there's an error.

**Progress reporting**

Progress reporting is available through the [Progress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1?view=netcore-3.1) class and [IProgress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1?view=netcore-3.1) interface. `IProgress<T>` allows a background task to send a strongly-typed message to the class that implements the interface. The `Progress<T>` implementation ensures the message is processed in the thread where it was created, typically the UI thread.

Assuming this is the message type:

```
class MyProgress
{
    public int Percent{get;set;}
    public string Message {get;set;}
}
```

The `RunCalculationsMethod` could be modified to accept and use a `IProgress<MyProgress>`;

```
public static int RunCalculationsMethod(string connectionstring, string foldername, 
                                        IProgress<MyProgress> progress)
{

    progress.Report(new MyProgress{Percent=0,Message="Starting"};
    ....
    progress.Report(new MyProgress{Percent=100,Message="Finished"};
}
```

The event handler would only need to create a `Progress<MyProgress>` and provide a method to update the UI. Let's assume `ProgressBarTemplate` had such a method, called `Update(string,int)` :

```
private async void RunCalculationsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var win_progressbar = new ProgressBarTemplate();
    IProgress<MyProgress> pg=new Progress<MyProgress>(pg=>
                        win_progressbar.Update(pg.Message,pg.Percent));
    win_progressbar.Show();
    try
    {
        //Update the UI
        var results=await Task.Run(()=> RunCalculationsMethod(...,pg));
        //Update the UI
    }
    finally
    {
        win_progressbar.Close();
    }
}
```

You can find a more thorough explanation in [Async in 4.5: Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/)

Comment: Panagiotis ty for the answer. If I go with this approach what is the point of having a progress bar then? I mean since I call the RunCalculationsMethod() from my main window and not from the ProgressBar Template Window. Also how to use ```Progress<T>```?

Comment: @NikSp I updated the answer showing how to use `Progress<T >` and linking to articles that explain both progress reporting and cancellation. The progress form should only be used to display progress. This way it can be reused by any asynchronous operation in the application.

Comment: Ok so now that my ProgressBarTemplate window that has this code ```void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        { int IsSuccessful = RunCalculationsMethod("Server=localhost;Database=ΓειαΣου;Integrated Security=SSPI", String.Format("folder_path"));
        }``` should I delete it?

Comment: Remove it from that form. Call it from the event handler. A progress form should only display progress. And remove the BGW completely

Comment: So I keep only the ```BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted```?

Comment: I showed you don't need BGW at all. There's simply no benefit to using it. Using `await Task.Run()` is a lot simpler. Instead of a UI component and several events, I showed how `RunCalculationsButton_Click` can use a single call to `Task.Run()` to run the SQL query.

Comment: Ok sorry that I repeat myself I need to understand this :). Also you have commented that ```//Update UI``` in your example. In the ```//Update the UI``` shall I put the rest of my code? meaning enabling the buttons and texts?

Comment: Yes. BTW since you're starting in Data science, check [Parallel and Asynchronous Programming](https://www.slideshare.net/PanagiotisKanavos/parallel-and-asynchronous-programming-itprodevconnections-2012) and [The Server-SIde Story: Παράλληλος και ασύγχρονος προγραμματισμός στο .NET](https://www.slideshare.net/PanagiotisKanavos/the-serverside-story-net-itprodevconnections-2014). Parallelism, concurrency and async are completely different beasts, requiring different classes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222519/discussion-between-niksp-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: Panagiotis I made the changes and indeed the code you posted works as expected. The only thing is that the progress bar is not updating...Meaning that it starts from 0, "Starting" and when the query ends turns to fully 100%, "Finished". I suppose there is no such a way to measure the progress of a query right?

Comment: @Panayiotis can you share your thoughts about this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64211995/performing-button-click-on-ui-window-is-not-sucessfull-through-an-open-thread

Answer (score 0):

You should use Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke because you try accessing the UI element. Except the main thread, other thread can not access the ui element.

Replace your code to

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>{
 // UI access code
});
```

Comment: Or just use `async/await` so no `Invoke` is needed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Normally, Your answer is collect. But sometimes is not working 
 when using nested async/await.

Comment: It's always working. When it seems it doesn't, it's a coding bug, eg someone tried to update the UI from inside the asynchronous method, or used `ConfigureAwait(false)` not realizing what it does

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos For example.
Like this button example.
private async void OnButtonClicked(object sende, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 UI Access is possible on this area.
 await Task.run(async() =>
 {
  UI Access is impossible on this area.
 }
}

Comment: That's a coding bug. You're trying to update the UI from a background thread. If you want to report progress from inside a background thread, use the `IProgress<T>` interface. There's no need for `Invoke` since 2012

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If use ConfigureAwait(false), then possible. But I don't like this pattern except special case. And above code is no bug. All UI element accessing library is using Dispatcher.Invoke on internal code.

Comment: That's another coding bug. `ConfigureAwait(false)` is only meant for library methods, to avoid forcing a return to the UI thread. The top-level call shouldn't use it